# UART communication protocol Arduino

Tags: arduino, protocols, communication, uart, baud-rate

I want to simulate Serial communication on Arduino.
Serial communication data is like **LOW | bits 0-7 | HIGH**. So I did the code below:

```cpp
uint8_t read8() {
      while(digitalRead(6));
      delayMicroseconds(52);
      uint8_t response = 0;
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        delayMicroseconds(104);
        response |= digitalRead(6) << i;
      }
      delayMicroseconds(156);
      return response;
    }
```

I am sending data via hardware serial TX to my custom RX pin. The first letter is correct, but another ones not. What is a mistake here? #9600

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `SoftwareSerial`?

Comment: I want do it by my own

Comment: Have you had a good look at the timing? Do you know the time of a digitalRead(6) call? There might be some jitter, too ( ISR Routines delaying read8() randomly )I'd minimize the last delayMicroseconds(156) and rather wait for the start bit in the beginning.